# put text at different height with tikz node

Tags: spacing, pdftex, positioning, tikz-node, picture-mode

I want to position a text at a certain height.  If put at (5,60) or any other number. It dosen't change the position on my pdf. What to do ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [text width=20cm,align=left] at (5,60) {Renseignements cliniques\\Suivi image hétérogène en mosaïque pulmonaire. Contexte néo endomètre post chimio Tx. Patiente asymptomatique\\TOMODENSITOMÉTRIE THORACIQUE 1\\Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v. pas d'acquisition\\ok reste restaurant\\je suis ici\\Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v.\\ok};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

~~

Just to highlight what is done here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}% just for hyphenation etc. later

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [text width=20cm,align=left, fill=gray!20]% filled node, so we see it
        at (5,60) 
        {Renseignements cliniques\\Suivi image hétérogène en mosaïque pulmonaire. 
        Contexte néo endomètre post chimio Tx. Patiente 
        asymptomatique\\TOMODENSITOMÉTRIE THORACIQUE 1\\Protocole a 
        faible dose après contraste i.v. pas d'acquisition\\ok 
        reste restaurant\\je suis ici\\Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v.\\ok};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure, if the screenshot I added is really what you want to achieve. You want to write a long text into a tikz-node? If so: why? Or do you just look for multiline display? // If you could position other nodes, what would your intended result look like? // As it is now, there is simply no room left to "breeze" for tikz ...

Comment: If I put at (5,90) instead of (5,60)  it shows it at the same height in my pdf. How to change the position of the text  in my pdf?

Comment: Try some nodes with less text, and coordinates much lower than 60. // How shall the result look like?

Comment: The coordinates in the tikzpicture are local to that tikzpicture. They aren't global coordinates related to the position on the page.

Comment: Is any way to position a node text at the end of a page ?

Comment: Yes, you can use the built-in `current page` node in a tikzpicture with options `remember picture` and `overlay`. There is also the package `tikzpagenodes` that adds the nodes `current page text area`, `current page footer area`, `current page header area` and `current page marginpar area`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `tikzpagenodes` package is a convenient way to place a node in the text area.

The example  uses the top left corner of the node (north  west) as the handle and the top left corner of the text area as the origin of coordinates.

The `current page text area node` was added by the package.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry} % changed <<<

\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}% added <<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]       
        
        \node [text width=10cm,align=left, anchor=north west, inner sep=0] at ([shift={(1,-4)}]current page text area.north west)  {Renseignements cliniques\\Suivi image hétérogène en mosaïque pulmonaire. Contexte néo endomètre post chimio Tx. Patiente asymptomatique\\TOMODENSITOMÉTRIE THORACIQUE 1\\Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v. pas d'acquisition\\ok reste restaurant\\je suis ici\\Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v.\\ok};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Remark: For hyphenation, space between words and moving to the next paragraph, it seems to me better to use a minipage in the node rather than \\. With text width=7cm for example

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, with the library `Calc` to position relative to the north west, with a north west anchor.

```
\node[anchor=north west,fill=gray!20] at ($(current page.north west)+(0,0)$)
```

We can change `(0,0)` by `(5,-5)` for example

> See pgfmanual section 17.13.2 Referencing the Current Page Node –
> Absolute Positioning

I added the `showframe` package for better visualization.

I propose to use a `minipage`, inside the node, you can easily add other environments like `itemize` for example, and spaces between words, hyphenations... are better managed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}%--- to see the layout, comment in the final document
\usetikzlibrary{calc}%<--- add
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \node[anchor=north west,fill=gray!20] at ($(current page.north west)+(0,0)$)
    {\begin{minipage}{10cm}
        Renseignements cliniques
        \begin{itemize}
            \item Suivi image hétérogène en mosaïque pulmonaire.
            Contexte néo endomètre post chimio Tx. Patiente
            asymptomatique
            \item TOMODENSITOMÉTRIE THORACIQUE 1
        \item Protocole a
            faible dose après contraste i.v. pas d'acquisition

            \item ok
            reste restaurant

            je suis ici

            Protocole a faible dose après contraste i.v.

            ok
        \end{itemize}
        \end{minipage}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]